# Switching from one control (textbox) to another makes disabled text box to be enabled WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, focus, controls

By pressing enter I am moving from one control to another, all of my controls are located in Grid, here is an image of that:

[image]

and what is issue here, ***in case some of my controls are disabled, when I "jump" to that control it's becoming enabled, and if one of my controls is button, its being fired like its mouse clicked***.

I dont know how to solve this,
this is how It looks right (my code) now and how I tried to solve this (To keep control disabled when I jumpt on it).

***Here is my xaml 3 textboxes, and 3 comboboxes***

```
<TextBox Name="txt1"   Grid.Row="0"  Grid.Column="1"         Margin="0,0,10,0" FontSize="15"  VerticalContentAlignment="Center" />
<TextBox Name="txt2"   Grid.Row="1"  Grid.Column="1"         Margin="0,5,10,0" FontSize="15" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
<TextBox Name="txt2"   Grid.Row="2"  TextWrapping="Wrap"     Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,5,10,0" FontSize="15"  />
<ComboBox Name="cmb1"  Grid.Row="3"  Grid.Column="1"         FontSize="15" Margin="0,5,10,0" />
<ComboBox Name="cmb2"  Grid.Row="4"  Grid.Column="1"         FontSize="15" Margin="0,5,10,0"  />
<ComboBox Name="cmb3"  Grid.Row="5"  Grid.Column="1"         FontSize="15" Margin="0,5,10,0" />

<Grid Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,5,10,0">
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="85*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="15*"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<ComboBox Name="cmb4" Grid.Column="0" IsEnabled="False" FontSize="15" >
    <ComboBox.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="#E0E4E5" />
    </ComboBox.Resources>
</ComboBox>

<Button x:Name="btnUnlockcmb4"
                Grid.Column="5"
                FontSize="15"
                BorderThickness="1.5"
                HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                Margin="4,0,0,0"
                Foreground="White"
                Background="White"
                BorderBrush="#0091EA"  Click="btnUnlockcmb4_Click">
                    <Button.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                            <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Button.Template>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Image Source="/Icons/unclock.png" Margin="4" Grid.Column="0" Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid>
                </Button>
            </Grid>
```

Acctually that are controls that i am "jumping from one to another".

And `cmb4` should stay disabled, just jump it away but dont change his state..

Here is my code:

```
private void Grid_PreviewKeyDown_1(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
            {


                UIElement element = e.Source as UIElement;

                //check is enabled = false as it is, so keep it disabled
                if (element.IsEnabled == false)
                {
                    element.IsEnabled = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    element.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

NOTICE BUTTON btnUnlockcm4, which is ussualy setting IsEnabled property to True on my cmb4, so by pressing enter is being fired I guess that is reason why it is enabling my cmb4?

EDIT:

Grid which holds controls:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,3" PreviewKeyDown="Grid_PreviewKeyDown_1">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="25*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="75*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="45" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="45"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="70"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="45"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="45"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="45"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="45"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="45"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="45"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="45"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="45" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="45"/>
                    <RowDefinition MinHeight="150"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="45" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Comment: A control shouldn't become enabled when you "jump" to it using the MoveFocus method. Please provide an example that demonstrates this issue.

Comment: @mm8 check for changes please I posted xaml also, I think button next to cmb4 is triggered on enter somehow? and that button ussually unlocking cmb4?

Comment: @mm8 again check for changes, I provided full XAML cuz there is button which is ussually used to unclock cmb4 so its somehow fired when Im pressing enter?

Comment: Please post the code of btnUnlockcmb4_Click.

Comment: @mm8 cmb4.IsEnabled=true;

Comment: @mm8 and yes its being fired!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the `IsTabStop` property of the `Button` to `false`:

```
<Button x:Name="btnUnlockcmb4"
         IsTabStop="False"
         Grid.Column="5"
         FontSize="15"
         ...
```

Comment: vote up + accept answer, ussualy procedure when you answering questions :D

Comment: I am glad I could help :)

Comment: one question for you please, how long you are active programming? You are very professional

Comment: is it true that I as a early beginner should read books about programming or digging like this +  watching tuts around is enought? :D :D :D :D

Comment: Please ask this kind of questions in the chat: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat

Comment: <3 :* :* :* :* :* :* :* :*